# Where is java? Java Control Pannel has disabled "View" button and Terminal still response with "No Java runtime present, requesting install"

Tags: macos, install, java, system-settings

I installed java from the oracle's website. Now I have a Java Control Panel in the System Preferences. But in the tab "Java" of Java Control Panel there is the button "View" disabled.

[image: Java Control Panel]

And if I ask the Terminal for `java -version` I get only:

```
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
```

Still having the following in the Java Control Panel (Your system has the recommended version of Java):

[image: java is up to date]

Starting some application, which requires java (e.g. Aptana Studio) it alerts with:

```
To open “AptanaStudio3,” you need to install a Java SE 6 runtime. Would you like to check for and install one?
```

What are the problems here? Sounds like the installation didn't enabled Java for the System.

## Update:

- OSX 10.8
- java 7u40 (JRE, not JDK)
- no previous version of java installed (clean install)
- logging in with different user accounts provides the same behaviour
- `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` is empty

Comment: Was there a previous version of Java installed?  Do you get the same results if you log in as a different user, or if you Safe Boot?  Have you tried reinstalling?

Comment: What java did you install? I suspect you did the JRE which does not now install /usr/bin/java :(

Comment: updated. I hope it answers all the questions

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for your problem? I currently have the same issue with OSX 10.11 and JDK1.8.0_101.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle's JRE for OSX does not install all you need for development work. This now means that you do not get /usr/bin/java which in earlier non OSX versions you did. The OSX JRE now provides enough to run Java plugins from your web browser.

If you want to do development you need the JDK currently Java SE 7u40 which is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html).